# vscode - XML regex sections

Tags: xml, replace, visual-studio-code

I stuck... in online regex Tools it works but not in vscode CMD+H

```
s*<ThingSaveData(?:.*\n){2}.*(MixRemove)(?:.*\n){1,56}.*<\/ThingSaveData>
```

List of Multi ThingSaveData with the same PrefabName, i want replace all ThingSaveData if PrefabName == MixRemove, the whole ThingSaveData section should removed

```
<ThingSaveData xsi:type="SlagSaveData">
  <ReferenceId>4142</ReferenceId>
  <PrefabName>MixRemove</PrefabName>
</ThingSaveData>
<ThingSaveData xsi:type="SlagSaveData">
  <ReferenceId>4143</ReferenceId>
  <PrefabName>MixOne</PrefabName>
</ThingSaveData>
<ThingSaveData xsi:type="SlagSaveData">
  <ReferenceId>4144</ReferenceId>
  <PrefabName>MixRemove</PrefabName>
</ThingSaveData>
```

to

```
<ThingSaveData xsi:type="SlagSaveData">
  <ReferenceId>4143</ReferenceId>
  <PrefabName>MixOne</PrefabName>
</ThingSaveData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^ *<ThingSaveData(?:.*\n){2}.*MixRemove(?:.*\n)\s*<\/ThingSaveData>
```

see https://regex101.com/r/3ybjHT/4

This part of your regex is wrong: `(?:.*\n){1,56}` you only want one of those groups, not up to 56.

Comment: Thanks, dont work i got over 220 childs with the PrefabName MixRemove

Comment: It works on your listed input.  Is your input different than what you showed in the question?